# Drupal 6 content reference

Tags: drupal

I have sports contents, so I create 2 content types season and teams, I added a reference field to the season content type which get the list of teams to select the teams in this season...
Now I need to create a view to list teams under specific season, so I know I should use relationship and argument but I failed to do it

So I need the steps to create a view to list teams under specific season

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View should look something like this: 
filter:

- node:type = season

Relationship:

- Relation to team

fields:

- node: title (for season)
- node: title (for team) + check to use relation to team

now about selecting season you can use: exposed filter for season OR you can use arguments
Settings for arguments:

- In arguments field select content(season)
- In path set structure of your URL with % in place of argument (season/%)

Hope this helps